# Where to find Logic App Action documentation?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I like to use Initialize Variable action in my logic app. I have looked at the online documentation for Logic App Actions;  however i can not find documentation for Initialize Variable action.
Where can i find documentation for all Logic App actions?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly says *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. A link to documentation would clearly be an *off-site resource*. Google and Bing are both designed to search for things and give you links to the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies this feature just got released but documentation is incoming for specifics. Any specific questions I can help with in the meantime? Today you can initialize to any number - but you cannot initialize a variable within a scope (must be global). Coming in next few weeks will be support strings, and then complex objects like arrays/collections